# prove inequality using methods of differential calculus

Tags: analysis

Could you help me prove following inequality ?
$$(x+y)^{\alpha}\le x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha} $$
$$x,y\ge 0, \alpha \le 1$$
I don't know from what start, I should use methods of differential calculus.

Comment: Define the funcion $f(x,y)=x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha}-(x+y)^{\alpha}$. Study this function...

Comment: Could you show your idea ? It seems to be very intresting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$, then the inequality is obvious. So let's assume $x,y>0$ and define $u=\frac{x}{x+y}$ and $v=\frac{y}{x+y}$. Then, $u,v\in(0,1)$, and we have
$$
\alpha\leq 1, u<1\implies (1-\alpha)\log u\leq 0\implies\log u\leq\log u^\alpha\implies u\leq u^\alpha.
$$
Similarly, $v\leq v^\alpha$ and so $1=u+v\leq u^\alpha+v^\alpha$, which is equivalent to the given inequality.

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $0<\alpha<1$, because otherwise the claim is trivial (or wrong). The function $f(x):=x^\alpha$ $(x\geq0)$ is concave, i.e., has a decreasing derivative $f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$. It follows that
$$f(x+y)-f(x)=\int_0^y f'(x+t)\>dt\leq \int_0^y f'(t)=f(y)\ ,$$
which is equivalent to the claim.